# Using isdigit() to determine if vector<string> index is letter or number

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

Trying to determine whether an index entry of a vector of strings is a letter or number. I am trying to use `isdigit()`, but it won't work because a suitable conversion can't be made using `isdigit(stof(eq[i]))`

Essentially, if I find that it is a letter, I want to change that value to 0.

```
#include string
#include vector

using namespace std;

vector <string> eq;
eq[0] = "a";
eq[1] = "3.5";
eq[2] = "7.5";

for (int i = 0; i < eq.size(); i++)
{
        try {
                isdigit(stof(eq[i]));
                throw(eq[i]);
            }
        catch (exception e) {
                cout << "eq[i] is not a number" << endl;
                eq[i] == "0";
                cout << "eq[i] = " << eq[i] << endl;
            }
}
```

The question is, how could I assess if an index value is a letter, and then if it is, replace that letter with a zero?

Comment: `stof` returns a `double`. How does doing an `isdigit` of that make sense? `isdigit` checks a single ***character***.

Comment: I understand why you might want to use `isdigit`, but why do you want to use `stof`???

Comment: `eq` has size zero on creation.  Assigning to `eq[0]`, `eq[1]`, and `eq[2]` without resizing beforehand causes undefined behaviour.       And don't use exceptions for flow control within a single function.   Look up the `if` statement.

Comment: `isdigit` checks a single character. `eq[1] = "3.5";` is a string   If you want to check the first character of `eq[1]` to see if it is a digit you can do `isdigit(eq[1][0])` but I don't think that's what you want to do.  If you are trying to convert `eq[1]` to a float then `stof` will work without checking the return value - but that's what the second parameter to `stof` is for - to tell you how much could be converted.  So you need to use the second parameter of `stof` instead of checking the return value with `isdigit`

Comment: It must be said that this isn't my original code, this is something I chucked together to attempt to recreate it. I used stof because the rest of the values are floats, and thought that if it failed on the initial one, I could reassign it and continue with my loop

Comment: I also must convert the index to a float later in the program, so my thought process was by checking if i COULD convert it to a float, i WOULD be able to change it later

Comment: @MCLyonzo Your vector contains strings with just single letters of the alphabet or does it have entire strings too like `"abc"`?

Comment: Hang on,  stof throws `std::invalid_argument ` if it couldn't convert anything so get rid of the isdigit and change the catch to accept `invalid_argument`: Like this: https://onlinegdb.com/S1UA4Rhwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just having a check as

```
if(eq[i].size() == 1 && std::isalpha(eq[i][0])) {
    eq[i] = "0";
}
```

Would that work for your case?

EDIT: In case you have something like `eq[3] = "abc";` i.e. entire strings rather just single letters, then something like this could be done:

```
if(
    std::any_of(eq[i].cbegin(), eq[i].cend(), [](char c) {
        return std::isalpha(c);
    })
) {
    eq[i] = "0";
}
```

Here's the documentation for [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

Comment: I was completely unaware of isalpha(). This works with the code I am using thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as @Peter notified, `eq` has size zero on creation, and assigning to `eq[0]`, `eq[1]`, and `eq[2]`, cause undefined behaviors. This can be solved by using `std::push_back()`.

Secondly, as @Jerry Jeremiah mentioned, `isdigit()` check if character is a **decimal** digit, so I don't see a point using that with `stof()`, which convert a **string** to a **float**.

This is the code that I modified from yours:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <string> eq;
    //sample data
    eq.push_back("a");
    eq.push_back("3.5");
    eq.push_back("7.5");
    eq.push_back("5");
    eq.push_back("xyz");

    for (int i = 0; i < eq.size(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            stof(eq[i]);
        }
        catch (exception e)
        {
            eq[i] = "0";
        }
        cout << "eq[" << i << "]" << " = " << eq[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
eq[0] = 0
eq[1] = 3.5
eq[2] = 7.5
eq[3] = 5
eq[4] = 0
```

Also, it might be more practical to use the second parameter of `stof()` (as @Jerry Jeremiah noted), and use `if` statement instead of `try-catch` (as @Peter noted).

***Note**: Running on Code::Blocks 20.03, g++ 6.3.0, Windows 10, 64 bit.

*More info:

`stof()` : https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/

`std::push_back()` : https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

`isdigit()` : https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/

Comment: This solution provided the desired result thank you for your input and the further reading